# How to control the focus listener upon action listener?

Tags: java

I have a panel. This panel has one text field and a button. The text field has focus listener to search some db value, if not value is written it shows an exit display message when tab. 
But, when edit the text field and button clicked without pressing tab key, following order occurs: 
1) focus lost 
2) action listener

Problem is the calling the focus lost, action listener should be call when 
  edit into text field ---> button clicked(without tab into text field)

Would you please kindly share your idea ?

Comment: Okay, I'm confused.  If the user leaves the field, without typing anything, display a message.  If the user leaves after typing something do nothing or call the action listeners???

Comment: Yea If the user leaves after typing something then call the action listener without calling lost focus.

Answer (score 1):

"*If the user leaves after typing something then call the action listner without calling lost focus*

Okay, firstly, you can't not have focus lost fired, however, you can ignore it

```
public void focusLost(FocusEvent evt) {
   if (textField.getText().length() > 0) {
       // call action
   } else {
      // show error message
   }
}
```

Okay, now that we can ignore the focus event, how to fire the action event?

Well, surprisingly, this really simple

```
button.doClick();
```